# Doubt related to interface instantiation in Java

Tags: java

The following program when run will product stackoverflow as output.

I want to know what is happening in the line where a TestA is being instantiated.

```
interface TestA { String toString(); }

class Test 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     // whats going on in this line ???
     System.out.println(new TestA() {public String toString() { return "stackoverflow"; } });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the quick help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are instantiating an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm), that implements the `TestA` interface.

This technique is very useful for e.g. [event listeners](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#innerClasses) in GUI programming, since it saves you from creating a bunch of named single-use classes.

Comment: What if the interface has >1 methods? Can we do a similar thing ?

Comment: Yes of course you just have to implement the other methods as well.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is to create an anonymus class that implements the interface.
To make it a little clearer you can write this as well:

```
interface TestA { String toString(); }

class Test 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    TestA test = new TestA()
    {
        public String toString()
        {
            return "stackoverflow";
        }
    };

    System.out.println(test);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following class is created on the fly (without any name) :

```
class Annonymous implements TestA 
{ 
    String toString() {
        return "stackoverflow";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Actually it will have a name. Something like TestA$1 I think

Comment: That is internal to java, it not something we can use or need to be aware of.